# Reduction of Order Methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

I have found two computationally similar yet conceptually dissimilar methods for applying reduction of order to an ODE.  The first starts with $y_{general} = vy_1$, while the second starts with $y_2 = vy_1$.  From there, the two more or less converge until the end; plug $vy_1$ into the ODE, do straightforward algebra, and make the obvious substitutions as needed.  The second method yields a second particular solution $y_2$, so from there the general solution must be constructed as $y_{general} = Cy_1 + Dy_2$.  However, the first method yields a general solution directly, without this final step.  Let's try the example $t^2 y'' + ty' - y = 0, y_1 = t$.

**Method 1**

$y_{general} = vt \implies t^2(v''t + 2v') + t(v't + v) - vt = 0 \implies v' = At^{-3} \implies v = At^{-2} + B \implies y_{general} = (At^{-2} + B)t = At^{-1} + Bt$

**Method 2**

$y_2 = vt \implies t^2(v''t + 2v') + t(v't + v) - vt = 0 \implies v' = At^{-3}$, but our goal is a particular solution, so we'll choose $A = 1$ and thus $v' = t^{-3} \implies v = t^{-2} + B$, but our goal is a particular solution, so we'll choose $B = 0$ and thus $v = t^{-2} \implies y_2 = (t^{-2})t = t^{-1} \implies y_{general} = Cy_1 + Dy_2 = Ct + Dt^{-1}$

$At^{-1} + Bt$ and $Ct + Dt^{-1}$ are equal.  We have arrived at the same general solution via both methods, but I find the computational-similarity-yet-conceptual-dissimilarity between the two quite suspicious.  Why do these two identically named methods always arrive at the same result, if in fact they do.

Comment: @Moo Isn't $y$ a placeholder for the general solution, and $y_2$ a placeholder for a particular solution (LI to $y_1$)?

Comment: Hmm, okay, I'll update the question when I get some time detailing the example I worked out.

Comment: @Moo Edited in an example

Comment: @Moo Yes, those are examples of Method 2.  Here is an external example of Method 1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQSFW8BIrY0

Comment: @Moo Afraid not, although I was able to learn Euler-Cauchy from it!  As far as Method II being precisely what was done in the Youtube Video, notice that Method II finds the second particular solution before the general solution, whereas the video finds the general solution directly (then points out the second particular solution at the end).  Also, in Method II the general solution's constants originate from taking linear combinations of particular solutions, whereas in the video they originate from integration.  As an aside, your link to solving Exact-Equations is for the first order variety.

Comment: The integration is due to having a separable equation.

Comment: Please note that each of $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions and so is their linear combination $y = y_1 + y_2$. I will have to watch at the video again to see if I notice some difference, but I don't think so.

Comment: Please see the update, hopefully it resolves your issue.

Comment: @Moo The update is close.  Your Case II is the same as my Method 1.  The only edit to Case I would be to choose a particular $c_1$ AND $c_2$, so that $y_2$ is a particular solution with no constants, then use the formula $y = c_1y_1 + c_2y_2$ at the end (or maybe this could a be Case III).  Now that the methods are understood, my question was to gain an intuition for they both lead to the same answer.  For example, a Ricatti ODE turns into a Bernoulli via a technique similar to reduction of order; does only one method work in general, and the other follow just for linear ODEs?

Comment: There are many problems that have several methods that can be used to solve them. There are some where only numerical methods would apply. For Reduction of Order, I think it would help if you went through the general case derivation and proof so that you can understand why both approaches work, see page 9 of https://www.math.upenn.edu/~moose/240S2015/slides8-03.pdf.

Comment: Even better, read the heading "An Observation..." of http://howellkb.uah.edu/public_html/DEtext/Part3/Reduction_of_Order

Answer (score 1):

We are given

$$\tag 1 t^2 y'' + ty' - y = 0, y_1 = t$$

This is a homogeneous linear equation and we can use many methods to find a general solution.

For example, we can solve this problem as a homogeneous linear equation, exact equation or use a substitution method like [*Reduction of Order*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx).

**Method I:** Solve as an Euler-Cauchy type equation.

Assume $$y = t^m \implies y' = m t^{m-1} \implies y'' = m(m-1) t^{m-2}$$

Substituting into $(1)$, we find that $m^2 - 1 = 0 \implies m = \pm~ 1$, which leads to the general solution $$y = c_1 t + \dfrac{c_2}{t}$$

**Method II:** Solve using Reduction of Order

We are told that a solution is $y_1 = t$.

We find the second solution using

$$y_2 = v t \implies y_2' = v' t + v, y_2'' = v'' t + 2 v'$$

Substituting into $(1)$

$$t^3 v'' + 3 t^2 v' = 0$$

Let $w = v' \implies w' = v''$, which leads to a separable equation and find $w = \dfrac{c_1}{t^3}$.

We now have

$$v' = w = \dfrac{c_1}{t^3} \implies v = \dfrac{c_1}{t^2}$$

Dropping the constants, we have two solutions as $y_1 = t, y_2 = v t = \dfrac{1}{t}$.

We can now write the general solution as

$$y = y_1 + y_2 = c_1 t + \dfrac{c_2}{t}$$

Compare that to Method I. This is precisely what was done in the [*Youtube Video*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQSFW8BIrY0).

You can also try the [*Exact-Equation*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Exact.aspx) approach as a third option.

There are **not** two different Reduction of Order methods.

**Update**

In the video, we are given

$$\tag 2 x^2 y'' + 5 x y' - 5 y = 0, y_1 = x$$

Let $y_2 = v x \implies y_2' = v' x + v \implies y_2'' = v'' x + 2 v'$

Substituting into $(2)$

$$x^3 v'' + 7 x^2 v' = 0$$

Let $w = v' \implies  w' = v''$, so

$$x^3 w' + 7x^2 w = 0$$

This is Separable Equation and we get $w = \dfrac{c_1}{x^7}$.

We now have $v' = \dfrac{c_1}{x^7}$ and anti-differentiating, we get

$$v = \dfrac{c_1}{x^6} + c_2$$

This is where the video deviates. What have two choices we can make. We can $1)$, choose $c_2$ to be zero or $2)$ keep $c_2$.

**Case 1:** If we choose $c_2 = 0$, we get

$$y_2 = v x = \left(\dfrac{c_1}{x^6}\right)x = \dfrac{c_1}{x^5}$$

the general solution in this case is

$$y = y_1 + y_2 = c_1 x + \dfrac{c_2}{x^5}$$

**Case 2:** If we choose $c_2 \ne 0$, we get the general solution

$$y = v x = \left(\dfrac{c_1}{x^6} + c_2\right)x = \dfrac{c_1}{x^5} + c_2 x$$

Additionally, I think you should work through a different [*example*](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/second/so_redord/so_redord.html) and [*these*](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/reduction-of-order-on-second-order-examples-1) using both methods.